# When will Tor 0.2.4 migrate into Debian Testing?

Tags: debian

[deb.torproject.org](http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/testing/main/binary-i386/Packages) currently contains 0.2.4.19-1~d79.jessie+1.

[jessie (testing)](http://packages.debian.org/jessie/tor) and [sid (unstable)](http://packages.debian.org/sid/tor) currently contain 0.2.3.25-1.

When will Tor 0.2.4 migrate into sid and/or testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About 10 days from now - I just uploaded it.  That'd make it right around x-mas.

If you want it sooner, you can also use our builds from [deb.tpo](http://deb.torproject.org/) -- [the tor website](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian) documents the sources.list entries.

Comment: It migrated sooner than expected and is in testing already.  See http://packages.debian.org/tor

Answer (score 2):

When exactly, is never known with Debian project. You can watch the Debian Package Tracking System for news and the todo of the package. If you want to make the package enter early, check the TODO and look what you do to help.

This is the Tor package page: http://packages.qa.debian.org/t/tor.html